# VB.NET Testing ftp connection

Tags: vb.net, ftp

so I am trying to upload files to my ftp, though I want it to test if the FTP details are correct. I found this code below, it works though it shows 'exists' when its connected but when it can't connect [with fake details] it doesnt do anything (I want an error to show saying it can't connect)

```
Imports System.Net

    Dim request = _
    DirectCast(WebRequest.Create _
    ("ftp://ftp.example.com/folder_here/"), FtpWebRequest)

    request.Credentials = _
    New NetworkCredential("user_here", "pass_here")

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

    Try
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = _
        DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            ' Folder exists here
            MsgBox("exists!")
        End Using

    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = _
        DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
        'Does not exist
        If response.StatusCode = _
        FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
            MsgBox("Doesn't exist!")
        End If
    End Try
```

How would I manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the using block might be catching the exception.  Try this instead

```
Try
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = _
    DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
        ' Folder exists here
    MsgBox("exists!")

Catch ex As WebException
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = _
    DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
    'Does not exist
    If response.StatusCode = _
    FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
        MsgBox("Doesn't exist!")
    End If
End Try
```